Flutter Web_socket_channel , Unhandled exception not upgraded to websocket
Im using web_socket_channel, for socket implementation. How ever when the url is added i'm getting a exception as follows,
Unhandled Exception: WebSocketException: Connection to 'wss://url#' was not upgraded to websocket

this is how im connecting the to the websocket
  WebSocketHelper(@Named('webSocketUrl') this.url, @Named('token') this.token)
      : channel = IOWebSocketChannel.connect(
          url,
          headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer $token'},
        ) {
    debugPrint("Connecting to WebSocket URL: $url with token: $token");
    _initializeWebSocket();
  }

What might be the reason for this?! and how can i tackle this?!

Could you test server side with Postman?

@chunhunghan i've checked with postman, im getting 502.

Could you test with online websocket tool like this https://websocketking.com/

@chunhunghan it's sorted. i used socket.io now. and it's working.
